# Virtual Disk Service Loader has stopped working

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, vmware-vsphere, diskmanagement

We have several relatively recent (less than 1 week) installations of Windows Server 2008 R2 Enterprise that are getting this error whenever we open Disk Management.  The application name is vdsldr.exe and the Problem Event Name is BEX64.

The windows firewall was turned off and the service disabled.  The Virtual Disk service was started (identical results when it is stopped).  The computers are virtual machines running on VSphere, so that could be part of the problem.

The strange thing is that Disk Manager worked fine when the VMs were first created.

Task Manager also seems to be crashing on these machines.  The problems are occuring on multiple VMs that are on different physical hosts.

Comment: vmtools and latest patches installed? what disk controller and disk type are the VMs setup with?

Comment: VMTools 4.0.0 build-236512.

Comment: I think the disk controller is LSI Logic Parallel and the vmdk types are SCSI.  Not sure if that is what you are looking for.

Comment: Well it sounds like an ok setup to me, presumably you're running them on ESX/i 4 Update 1 too right?

Comment: Yes, ESX 4 Update 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sophos Antivirus 7.6.18 (Updated 4/15/2010) seems to be causing these problems.  On a fresh build the problems don't occur until it is installed and uninstalling it fixed the problem.